# How to change column position in my report using BIRT tool

Tags: report-designer

I have been using birt tool(birt-rcp-report-designer-4.6.0) to design reports(.rptdesign file). [i tried xml source to change columns order in my table but it doesn't work and .](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WMrehiLut7bnJ4Y3pYYm1yZE0/view?usp=sharing) [[drag option though]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WMrehiLut7T1VRT2ZTcThrNjg/view?usp=sharing) are there any other way to change column alignment in my table in easy manner because i have to do column alignment for bunch of reports.what i mean by column alignment is switching column position. tnx in advance.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you did and what the result was. Post some sample data.

Comment: there is no change in my result after i modified position of column in xml.

Answer (score 0):

As the simplest solution I found to move column around is:

1. Create a new column where you want it to be, selecting a nearest column, then right-click -> Insert -> Column to the right/left (Naming could be different for your language)
2. Cut out the column you want to move (Ctrl+X)
3. Select newly created column and paste there column you cutted out before.